# has_many join display issue

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Newbie Rails question... I know there's a better way to do this. I need help understanding why this isn't working like I thought it should.
I'm doing a simple join tables using a "has_many" relationship with a pre-existing database. I need to keep the "non-rails" friendly titles.

Here's the output <%= room.levels %> as seen in the browser: `[#<Level Name: "01 - FIRST FLOOR">]`
I'd like to only see 01 - FIRST FLOOR without all of the other information.

I have two tables. :rooms and :levels

Here's the schema for the two tables:

```
create_table "levels", :primary_key => "Id", :force => true do |t|
t.integer "TypeId"
t.integer "DesignOption"
t.string  "Name"
t.float   "Elevation"

create_table "rooms", :primary_key => "Id", :force => true do |t|
t.integer "DesignOption"
t.integer "PhaseId"
t.string  "Comments"
t.float   "Volume"
t.float   "Perimeter"
t.integer "Level"
t.string  "Occupancy"
t.float   "Area"
t.string  "Number"
t.string  "Name"
end

 add_index "rooms", ["Id"], :name => "Id", :unique => true
```

Here's the app/model/room.rb:

```
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :Area, :Level, :Name, :Number, :Perimeter, :PhaseId, :Elevation
   has_many :levels, :primary_key => 'Level', :foreign_key => 'Id', :select => 'Name' set_primary_key :Id
end
```

Here's a snippet from the app/views/rooms/index.html.erb:

```
<% @rooms.each do |room| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= room.Name %></td>
    <td><%= room.Number %></td>
    <td><%= room.PhaseId %></td>
    <td><%= room.levels %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', room %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_room_path(room) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', room, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
```

Thanks!

Comment: By convention (and rails emphasizes convention!) your attributes / method names (like `Name`, `Number`, ...) should be lowercased

Comment: The author of this question explicitly said "`I need to keep the "non-rails" friendly titles.`"

Comment: using an exist export from architectural software... would prefer to keep data intact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<td><%= room.levels.map(&:Name).join(', ') %></td>
```

**Why your code didn't work** on the first place? because room.levels returns an array of Level objects. You need to loop through them to get each name, and then display it.

```
room.levels
# => returns all the level objects associated

room.levels.map(&:Name)
# => collect each name of the level objects (makes an array of (String) names)

room.levels.map(&:Name).join(', ')
# => Return a nice String with all the levels name with ", " between each.
```

Comment: Thanks! You Rock!  <td><%= room.levels.map(&:Name).join(',') %></td>

Answer (score 0):

because `levels` gives you a collection back. you need to iterate over `room.levels` and there you get the elements

Answer (score 0):

With you current Schema, Room belongs_to level, there is no way a room can have many levels (unless not with only that two tables)

```
create_table "rooms", :primary_key => "Id", :force => true do |t|
...
t.integer "Level" # One-to-One relation
```

So, what you need is something like:

```
# Model
class Room < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :Area, :Level, :Name, :Number, :Perimeter, :PhaseId, :Elevation
   belongs_to :level, :primary_key => 'Level', :foreign_key => 'Id', :select => 'Name'

end

# View
<td><%= room.level.name %></td>
```